# jQuery: Is it possible to attach fields/methods to a jQuery wrapper object?

Tags: javascript, jquery, plugins

I'm trying to write a plugin that will add a few methods to a jQuery wrapper object.  Basically, I want to initialize it like this:

```
var smart = $('img:first').smartImage();
```

The 'smartImage' plugin would attach 2 methods to the object referenced by 'smart', so I'll be able to do something like:

```
smart.saveState();
// do work
smart.loadState();
```

Unfortunately, I can't figure out how to attach these 2 methods to the wrapper object.  The code I have follows the typical jQuery plugin pattern:

```
(function($)
{
    $.fn.smartImage = function()
    {
        return this.each(function()
        {
            $(this).saveState = function() { /* save */ }
            $(this).loadState = function() { /* load */ }
        }
    }
 }
```

After I call smartImage(), neither 'saveState' nor 'loadState' is defined.  What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You cannot attach methods/properties in they way you have demonstrated, because as you said, the jQuery object is just a wrapper around whatever DOM elements it contains. You can certainly attach methods/properties to it, but they will no persist when they are selected by jQuery again.

```
var a = $('.my-object');
a.do_something = function(){ alert('hiya'); }
a.do_something(); // This alerts.

var b = $('.my-object');
b.do_something(); // Freak-out.
```

If you want a method to exist on the jQuery object when recovering it a second time, it needs to be assigned to `jQuery.fn`. So you *could* define your secondary method, assign it to the jQuery.fn, and use the jQuery data setup to maintain state for you...

```
$.fn.setup_something = function()
{
    this.data('my-plugin-setup-check', true);
    return this;
}

$.fn.do_something = function()
{
    if (this.data('my-plugin-setup-check'))
    {
        alert('Tada!');
    }
    return this;
}

var a = $('.my-object').setup_something();
a.do_something(); // Alerts.
$('.my-object').do_something(); // Also alerts.
```

I suggest you look at http://docs.jquery.com/Internals/jQuery.data and http://docs.jquery.com/Core/data#name

Comment: I didn't know about this 'data' map thing, which turns out to be exactly what I wanted.  Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

You are actually returning a jQuery object in the smartImage() function.  That is the correct way to write a jQuery plugin, so that you can chain that with other jQuery functions.

I'm not sure if there is a way to do what you want.  I would recommend the following:

```
(function($) {
     var smartImageSave = function() { return this.each(function() { } ); };
     var smartImageLoad = function() { return this.each(function() { } ); };

     $.fn.extend( { "smartImageSave":smartImageSave, 
                     "smartImageLoad":smartImageLoad });
 });

 var $smart = $("img:first");
 $smart.smartImageSave();
 $smart.smartImageLoad();
```

That's one technique that I am familiar with and have used successfully.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not entirely sure why you are designing your plugin this way - you might want to consider something along the lines of jonstjohn's suggestion - but the following should be similar to what you're asking for:

```
jQuery.fn.extend({
    smartImage: function() {
        return {
            saveState: function() { /* save */ },
            loadState: function() { /* load */ }
        };
    }
});
```